# Framework7: Open the same page and stack it in page history

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, html-framework-7

I have a Cordova Android app which uses Framework7.

Can I stack the same page over and over on the page history?

Let's say I'm on page "category.html".

I'd like to navigate a nested subcategory. Since the depth of the category tree is unknown a-priori, I'm reusing the same "category.html" page with updated content.

Unfortunately, if I call:

```
app.router.navigate("/category.html");
```

Framework7 doesn't load the page (because I'm already in "category.html").
I tried reloading the page:

```
app.router.navigate(app.views.main.router.url, {reloadCurrent: true, history:true, ignoreCache:true});
```

It works, but the "new" category.html page doesn't get stacked in the page history (if I go back from a subcategory, I'd like to go back to the parent category)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

History Urls are stored in **router.history** array and it is possible to access it at Jsx level.

You can refer lib file in the path

> node_modules/framework7/modules/router/clear-previous-history.js

to see how they handle history array.

Hope this helps.